# AWS Lambda: deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, sqlite, aws-lambda

I have a website already hosted on AWS Lambda and testing to see if the api works. But when I run it on the website it gives me the error.

> NotSupportedError at /api/
> deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher
> Request Method:   GET
> Request URL:  https://2dx7zf9yt5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/
> Django Version:   4.2.4
> Exception Type:   NotSupportedError
> Exception Value:
> deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher
> Exception Location:   /var/task/django/db/backends/sqlite3/_functions.py, line 45, in register
> Raised during:    blog_api.views.PostList
> Python Executable:    /var/lang/bin/python3.11
> Python Version:   3.11.6
> Python Path:
> ['/var/task',
> '/opt/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
> '/opt/python',
> '/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
> '/var/runtime',
> '/var/lang/lib/python311.zip',
> '/var/lang/lib/python3.11',
> '/var/lang/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
> '/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
> '/opt/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
> '/opt/python',
> '/var/task']
> Server time:  Tue, 31 Oct 2023 12:14:06 +0000

I saw a different related question that shows me that I have to install pysqlite3, but I keep ending up with the error

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysqlite3

Even when I installed the wheel, setuptools and cmake.

I am running Python3.11.3

I am hoping to learn django from this experience hosting on awls but its abit tough.

Comment: You won't be able to deploy sqlite database to lambda just by the nature. There is no persistent storage in lambda functions by design, it's not a regular server. Your database will be destroyed quickly. You likely need and RDS instance (postgres, or maybe Aurora which is cheaper for non-heavy workloads).

Comment: I am using Zappa to link both the Lambda and S3 Bitbucket together for a database. Isn't that enough? Or do I need more?

Comment: Hm, S3 bucket to store sqlite database? This may flight, but the performance will be terrifying.

Comment: Terrifying meaning? I am just trying to learn AWS for a job, but currently I am just stuck with the project having the issue of "AWS Lambda: deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher"

Comment: Your function will have to fetch sqlite file from s3 bucket - it's enormous network overhead. Also it's one big race condition and will break for concurrent executions. Could you share the tutorial or example you're trying to follow? Using sqlite is good only for local development and only for the very beginning - even locally you'd better spin a database container with postgres instead.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaiL4sbaj_o

What I am trying to do is load up some stuff from a database to display on my own portfolio.
This is the guy I am learning from to create my own AWS server. Do you have a good tutorial to follow to implement, python and any database for a server?

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off-topic here. From a quick glance, this looks relatively good (since you're using Zappa, it should be a good fit): https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/rds-database-serverless-django-zappa-aws-lambda/ (sorry, can't search for youtube tutorials - video examples are too inconvenient for me). Basically you need to create a RDS database instead of your SQLite and grant access appropriately.

Comment: Alright thank you I will try to work it out using either PostgreSQL or DynamoDB to create a db for now. thank you. I thought I could use a sqlite3 db to serve as a testgrounds in place of an actual db

Comment: aside from all the other comments, sqlite3 comes shipped as standard with python. So does not need installing.

Answer (score 0):

Frame challenge: you are solving a wrong problem.

Django requires a [database backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/) to store its data.

You are trying to use SQLite as a backend for your Django installation.

SQLite is an embedded database engine. It's a library which, at the end of the day, converts your SQL queries to file system calls. It requires that the database files reside on a filesystem accessible by your application.

Lambda is not designed for workloads that have a shared filesystem as a dependency. Technically, you can [mount a persistent shared EFS volume](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/) to be reusable by multiple Lambda invocations. But that's an edge use case, and SQLite [doesn't work well with NFS](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) (of which EFS is a flavor):

> SQLite uses reader/writer locks to control access to the database. (Under Win95/98/ME which lacks support for reader/writer locks, a probabilistic simulation is used instead.) But use caution: this locking mechanism might not work correctly if the database file is kept on an NFS filesystem. This is because fcntl() file locking is broken on many NFS implementations. You should avoid putting SQLite database files on NFS if multiple processes might try to access the file at the same time.

You would be better off using a multi-user RDBMS which you can comminicate with over the network. You can run PostgreSQL, MySQL and MariaDB as managed services on RDS, as standalone Docker containers or just install them on an EC2 instance.

It does take a little bit of work compared to SQLite (which Django creates as needed), but it's the only reliable way to make Django work on Lambda.